# How to get the material ui Button component content value onclick

Tags: reactjs

[image]

How can i get the value Add Property onClick?

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

I guess then this is what you are looking for:

```js
onClick={(event) => {
  console.log(event?.target?.textContent);
}
```

### Original Answer

Do you have access to `isLastStep`? If yes, you could just use that to determine which strings is shown in the button like:

```js
<Button
  type="submit"
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  className={classes.button}
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(isLastStep ? "Add Property" : "Next");
  }
>
  { isLastStep ? "Add Property" : "Next" }
</Button>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, can you please be more speficic providing a different example of what you want to do?

Comment: No, I need to get "Add Property" or "Next" when i click the <Button> component.

Comment: @BIPLABPAUL I updated the answer, let me know if now it helps you :)